# How to interpret tf.layers.dropout training arg

Tags: python, tensorflow

For `tf.layers.dropout()` the documentation for the `training` arg is not clear to me.

The [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L340) states:

```
training: Either a Python boolean, or a TensorFlow boolean scalar tensor
      (e.g. a placeholder). Whether to return the output in training mode
      (apply dropout) or in inference mode (return the input untouched).
```

My interpretation is that depending on if `training = True` or `training = False` the dropout will be applied. However, it's not clear to me if `True` or `False` will apply the dropout (ie. which is in training mode). Given that this is an optional argument, I expected that tf.layers.dropout() would apply by default, but the default is `False` which intuitively `training=False` would suggest that the default is not training.

It appears that in order for tf.layers.dropout() to actually apply, one would need something like:

`tf.layers.dropout(input, 0.5, training = mode == Modes.TRAIN)`

This is not very obvious to me from the documentation as `training` is an optional argument.

Does this appear to be the correct implementation of `tf.layers.dropout`? Why would the `training` flag just not automatically be tied to `Modes.TRAIN` as the default and then need to be adjusted for other cases? The default being `training=False` seems to be very misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of `dropout()` and its `training` argument is correct. However, an automatic `Modes.TRAIN` check as you suggest is impossible. A mode is usually tied to an [estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) `model_fn()` as an optional parameter. Estimators constitute an higher-level abstraction and are not required in a TensorFlow model.

As to why TensorFlow designed their API with a `false` default value, we can only speculate. An explanation would be that the `layers` abstraction as a whole was intended to default to an inference mode, thereby explaining the `dropout() training` default value.